# Change Proxy while testing via jmeter

Tags: rest, api, testing, proxy, jmeter

I need to simulate real user behavior. Each of real user must have new IP. Can I set Proxy programmatically via jmeter ? Example - I launch tests without Proxy, then, after 1-2 sec I activate  the proxy and after 3-4 sec - I disable. Is that possible without stopping the test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to spoof the ids then you can use csv to get the different IPs (proxy IPs) and pass them as a variable in the HTTP Request Server Name field under advanced tab as shown below:-

[image]

Please check [this](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter) article for more information.

I hope this help.

Comment: Input can be taken from csv file. You can use txt or excel to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to define a proxy **per [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)**, the relevant configuration lives on "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

[image: JMeter Proxy Server Per Request]

A better option would be going for [IP Spoofing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter), this way you will be able to bind each virtual user to a real (or virtual) IP address so source address will be different.